# Dense subset of a dense subset is a dense subset?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Given a set $A$, we say a subset $B\subseteq A$ is dense in $A$ if $cl(B)=A$

> Prove or Disprove: If $A$ is a normed space and $B\subseteq A$ is dense in $A$ and $C\subseteq B$ is dense in $B$, can we say that $C$ is dense in $A$?

I guess it is true but have not been able to show the diagonalization arguement.

Comment: Hint: It's probably easiest to use the condition that $B$ is dense in $A$ if and only if for each nonempty subset $U$ of $A$, we have $U\cap B \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: You can try an $ε/2$ argument with the help of the triangle inequality

Comment: Yes, notice that : $cl(C) = cl(cl(C)) = cl(B) = A$.

Comment: If $a$ is close to $b$ and $b$ is close to $c$, then $a$ is close to $c.$

Answer (score 1):

This is true for a general topological space.  Recall that $B$ is dense in $A$ if and only if for every nonempty open subset $U$ of $A$, we have $U\cap B \ne \emptyset$.  Now, say we have a nonempty open subset $U\subseteq A$.  Then since $B$ is dense in $A$, $U\cap B \ne \emptyset$; and also, by the definition of the subspace topology, $U\cap B$ is an open subset of $B$.  Therefore, since $C$ is dense in the subspace topology on $B$, we have $(U\cap B) \cap C \ne \emptyset$.  It follows that $U\cap C\ne \emptyset$; and since $U$ was arbitrary, this shows that $C$ is dense in $A$.